# Populating an array with elements

Tags: c#

I have this code right here, how can I fill the last two elements with let's say the names "John" and "Alex" ?

```
string[] myAry = new string[5] { "Tom", "Mary", "Sam", "", "" };
```

Comment: `string[] myAry = new string[5] { "Tom", "Mary", "Sam", "John", "Alex" };`

Comment: Or `myAry[3] = "John";`